# How to interpret scatter plots generated by linear regression and nonlinear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, nonlinear-regression

When I do my regression work, I find there are some problem which I can not interpret. I use [Catboost regression](https://catboost.ai/)  which is a kind of improved version of gradient boosting on decision trees and [Lasso regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) which is a version of **Linear Regression with L1 regularization**. I use 10-fold cross-validation to get each fold prediction and plot the scatter map. The map is as follows

[image: scatter map]

However, two problems are in **Lasso Map**, one is that it appears **negative prediction**, beacuse it is linearity, the appeared negative prediction is normal. others is that it appears **truncated prediction data (red line)**. why does Lasso appear **truncated prediction data** compared to CatBoost regression?

I do not understand it. Can you help me?